# I get zero or negative values for N when designing a butterworth filter using buttord()

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter

These are the required specifications for my low pass Butterworth filter.

[image]

```
delta_l = 0.2929;
delta_h = sqrt(0.1);

passband_min = 1-delta_l;
stopband_max = delta_h;

% the passband and stopband edge frequencies, normalized from 0 to 1 where
% 1 corresponds to pi rad/sample
Wp = 0.25; %*pi
Ws = 0.4; %*pi

%in the input to buttord(), Rp is the passband ripple
%"no more than Rp dB of passband ripple"
Rp = mag2db(delta_l)

%in the input to buttord(), Rs is the stopband attenuation
Rs = mag2db(1-delta_h)

[n, Wn] = buttord(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs)
```

The output is

```
Rp =

  -10.6656


Rs =

   -3.3018


n =

    -1


Wn =

    0.3805
```

Which is obviously wrong.

Using math I get a cutoff frequency of 0.7854 with n = 3.
Once I get these values, I plan on putting them into the butter() function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try passing positive numbers for the ripple specifications?  "Garbage in, garbage out"

Comment: Are you not surprised yourself that you are designing a filter with a stronger attenuation in the passband compared to the stopband?

Comment: have look at this [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38564/whats-the-pass-band-ripple-and-stop-band-attenuation-of-a-digital-filter)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong formula for attenuation:

Attenuation level in dB = 20 * log10(vout/vin)

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem?